# Parse <div> with two <p> elements, only grabbing <p> with <span> element containing text "A:"

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Here's the section of source I'm working with:

```
<div class="entry-content">

  <div class="at-above-post-cat-page addthis_tool" data-url="https://www.factcheck.org/2018/03/meme-falsely-claims-exposed-snopes-com/"></div>

  <p><span><span>Q:</span> </span>Did FactCheck.org expose Snopes.com as an “extremely liberal propaganda site”?</p>

  //grab this <p> element always containing <span>A:</span>: 
  <p><span><span>A:</span> </span>No. That false claim was made in a meme circulating online.<!-- AddThis Advanced Settings above via filter on get_the_excerpt --><!-- AddThis Advanced Settings below via filter on get_the_excerpt --><!-- AddThis Advanced Settings generic via filter on get_the_excerpt --><!-- AddThis Share Buttons above via filter on get_the_excerpt --><!-- AddThis Share Buttons below via filter on get_the_excerpt --></p>

  <div class="at-below-post-cat-page addthis_tool" data-url="https://www.factcheck.org/2018/03/meme-falsely-claims-exposed-snopes-com/"></div>

  <p><!-- AddThis Share Buttons generic via filter on get_the_excerpt --></p>   

</div>
```

I'm only interested in grabbing the `<p>` element with `<span> A: </span>`

When I do this:

```
let rating = $(meta).children('div.entry-content').children('p').text().trim();
```

I get the text from both `<p>` elements

When I do this:

```
let rating = $(meta).children('div.entry-content').children('p').next().text().trim();
```

or this:

```
let rating = $(meta).children('div.entry-content').children('p').eq(1).text().trim();
```

I get an empty string

Comment: this works with cheerio (without the JavaScript comment in the middle of the content) : `$(meta).children('div.entry-content p').eq(1).text()`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. If you care to submit an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 1):

You ca get the 2nd `p` child with:

```
$("p:nth-of-type(2)")
```

or the `p` that specifically has A: with:

```
$("p:has(span:has(span:contains(A:)))")
```

or you can mess around outside of css like mmm suggests